# Devolver usuarios consulta node y mysql dentro de for

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, typescript

estoy tratando de ejecutar unas consultas con unos id's de usuarios que obtengo de otra consulta, el problema es que quiero almacenar estos usuarios en un arreglo asi que como son varias consultas lo que hice fue crear un forEach y dentro de este hago dichas consultas, pero parece que se ejecuta todo el for y al final el arreglo d queda vacio.
Se que debe ser algo que tenga que ver con las funciones asincronas pero no se como usarla en este caso.

```
function getEstudiantesProyecto(tabla, estudiantes){
let estudiantesProyecto = [];


    estudiantes.forEach(elemento => {

        connection.query(`SELECT * FROM ${tabla} WHERE id = '${elemento.idUsuario}'`, (err, data)=> {
               
            if(err) return error;
            estudiantesProyecto.push(data[0]);
     })
       
    });
    console.log('devuelve ', estudiantesProyecto)
```

}

Comment: ¿Qué módulo estás usando para mysql?

Comment: @ricardo-dlc estoy usando el modulo de mysql

Comment: Me temo que por la naturaleza asincrónica de la petición, no vas a poder hacer lo que tienes en mente (devolver de la función el array). Tendrás que arreglártelas para  llamar dentro del callback lo que sea que necesites hacer cuando te lleguen los datos. Lo que sí que puedes hacer es [quitarte ese ciclo `for` de arriba](https://pastebin.com/21NdiYLw) y hacerlo todo en una sola consulta. Supuse estás usando la librería recomendada para [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) en node (se llama mysql2).

Comment: Como menciona el compañero @JaimeMenéndez creo que tendrías que cambiar el enfoque de tu código para de cierta forma "esperar" la respuesta de tu consulta. Como dato, no es que el array se quede vacío, si no que por la forma en como funciona node, aunque tu código no haya terminado de ejecutarse, continuará con el flujo, en este caso, el `console.log` no esperará a que se rellene tu array, por eso pareciera que está vacío. Para no cambiar mucho podrías hacer uso de una [Promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Answer (score 1):

No tengo forma de probarlo, pero creo que algo así te podría funcionar:

```
async function getEstudiantesProyecto(tabla, estudiantes) {
  let estudiantesProyecto = [];

  //Creas una promesa para cada consulta
  const promises = estudiantes.map(elemento => {
    return new Promise((reject, resolve) => {
      connection.query(`SELECT * FROM ${tabla} WHERE id = '${elemento.idUsuario}'`, (err, data)=> {               
            resolve(err ? null: data[0]);
        })
  });

  //Obtienes los resultados de cada promesa, obtienes solo el valor de la respuesta y quitas del array los que sean nulos
  const result = (await Promise.allSettled(promises)).map(r => r.value).filter(Boolean);
  
  return result;
}

(async () => {
  const estudiantesProyecto = await getEstudiantesProyecto(tabla, estudiantes);
  console.log('devuelve ', estudiantesProyecto);
})()
```

Aunque igual no se cual sea el resto de tu código, creo que es una manera muy poco óptima de consultar, porque no consultas todos los estudiantes en una sola consulta?

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez eso lo sé... pero no desde el contexto de la pregunta, no es muy claro desde donde se hace el llamado a la función `getEstudiantesProyecto`, ya dependiendo de eso se puede buscar la solución. De todas maneras voy a agregar código para solventar el problema